# Unit Test for BPMN file

Tags: unit-testing, activiti, bpmn

Hi we are using Activiti 6.0.0 along with Spring-Boot application on Spring Microservices. I have to write an Unit tests on bpmn files which have DelegateExpression. Can anyone point me the some ideas for UnitTest?

Answer (score 11):

I've done a fully tested activiti project before. upon your question i uploaded it on my github [activiti-test](https://github.com/mehditahmasebi/bpm/tree/master/activiti-test), so you can access complete and executable source of this answer. This project is based on Maven, Activiti, Spring, H2 and JUnit. but if you want to run it over Spring Boot so you can see my other sample project [Spring-boot kickstart sample](https://github.com/mehditahmasebi/spring/tree/master/spring-boot). 
The activit-test project structure :

1. **Maven Project POM.xml**
   You can import (activiti-test) project as existing Maven Project in your IDE or anywhere you are comfortable.

Important dependency is :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    .
    .
    .
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${activiti.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    .
    .
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    .
    .
    .
```

**2. applicationContext.xml**

The important code block is starting activiti engine (bean: processEngineConfiguration)

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
    <!-- H2 -->
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:activiti;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000"  />
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
    <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" /> <!-- important and valid values : true,false,create-drop -->
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="true" />
    <property name="asyncExecutorEnabled" value="true" />
    <property name="asyncExecutorActivate" value="true" />
</bean>
```

**3. Create activiti database Schema**

At the sample code there is a class bean named *InitDb* that call

```
org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSchemaCreate.main(null);
```

**4. Prepare Test environment**

There is a class named *BaseTest* to make other testing easy :
first part get instance of activiti service and the second part is a method to deploy a process by BaseTest child class that comes in the next code block.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(BaseTest.APPCONTEXT)
public abstract class BaseTest implements ApplicationContextAware {

    public static final String APPCONTEXT = "/applicationContext.xml";

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BaseTest.class);
    public static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    protected ProcessDeployer processDeployer;

    @Autowired
    protected MyProcessEngine processEngine;

    protected RuntimeService runtimeService;
    protected TaskService taskService;
    protected RepositoryService repositoryService;
    protected HistoryService historyService;

    @PostConstruct  
    public void init() {
        runtimeService = processEngine.getProcessEngine().getRuntimeService();
        taskService = processEngine.getProcessEngine().getTaskService();
        repositoryService = processEngine.getProcessEngine().getRepositoryService();
        historyService = processEngine.getProcessEngine().getHistoryService();
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    private List<String> deploymentIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Before
    public void deploy()
    {
        if(deploymentIds.size() > 0)
            for(String deploymentId : deploymentIds)
                repositoryService.deleteDeployment(deploymentId);
        deploymentIds.clear();

        long beforeCount = processDeployer.getDeployedCount();
        logger.info("Number of Process Deployed Before start to deploy any new thing : " + beforeCount);
        if(getBpmnFiles() != null)
            for(String bpmn : getBpmnFiles())
            {           
                if(bpmn != null)
                    deploymentIds.add(processDeployer.deploy(bpmn));
            }
        logger.info(processDeployer.getDeployedCount() + " Processes Deployed Successfully");
    }

    protected abstract String[] getBpmnFiles(); 
    .
    .
    .
}
```

**5. Simple Test Process Model**

First of all we need a bpmn diagram you can find (SampleProcess.bpmn)
This process has a start event, one user task and an end event.

bpmn xml content is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn2:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bpmn2="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" id="Definitions_1" targetNamespace="http://org.eclipse.bpmn2/default/process">
  <bpmn2:process id="process_1" name="sampleProcess">
    <bpmn2:startEvent id="StartEvent_1">
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_2</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:startEvent>
    <bpmn2:endEvent id="EndEvent_1">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_3</bpmn2:incoming>
    </bpmn2:endEvent>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_2" sourceRef="StartEvent_1" targetRef="UserTask_1"/>
    <bpmn2:userTask id="UserTask_1" name="User Task 1">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_2</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_3</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:userTask>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_3" sourceRef="UserTask_1" targetRef="EndEvent_1"/>
  </bpmn2:process>
</bpmn2:definitions>
```

**6. Run a Test**

After all you can run a test like this :

```
public class SampleProcessTest extends BaseTest {

    @Override
    protected String[] getBpmnFiles() {
        return new String[] {"com/test/activiti/sampleProcess/SampleProcess.bpmn"};
    }
    @Test
    public void sampleFlowTest()
    {
        ProcessInstance pi = super.runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("process_1");
        Task ut1 = super.taskService.createTaskQuery()
                                        .processInstanceId(pi.getId())
                                        .active()
                                        .singleResult();
        assertNotNull(ut1);
        super.taskService.complete(ut1.getId());
        HistoricProcessInstance historicProcess = super.historyService.createHistoricProcessInstanceQuery()
                                                                        .processInstanceId(pi.getId())
                                                                        .finished()
                                                                        .singleResult();

        assertNotNull("Process must be finished",historicProcess);

    }

}
```

**7.Delegate Expression example**

At the source link there is lots of example of DelegateExpression, but for now we create a sample BPMN process has two service tasks that define by  DelegateExpression to Autowire with Spring bean :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
  <process id="awProcess" name="My process" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <serviceTask id="servicetask1" name="Service Task" activiti:delegateExpression="${awServiceTask1}"></serviceTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="servicetask1"></sequenceFlow>
    <serviceTask id="servicetask2" name="Service Task" activiti:delegateExpression="${com.test.activiti.autowiredservicetask.AWServiceTask2}"></serviceTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="servicetask1" targetRef="servicetask2"></sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="servicetask2" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>      
</definitions>
```

and AWServiceTask1 :
    @Component("awServiceTask1")
    public class AWServiceTask1 implements JavaDelegate {

```
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AWServiceTask1.class);
    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Object Identity : " + this.toString());
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        logger.info("awServiceTask1 is created");
    }

}
```

and similar way is the code of AWServiceTask2, you can find the fully source at [activiti-test](https://github.com/mehditahmasebi/bpm/tree/master/activiti-test).
and test class is :

```
public class TestAWServiceTask extends BaseTest {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestAWServiceTask.class);
    public static String KEY = "awProcess";

    @Test
    public void autoWireTest()
    {
        processDeployer.printAllProcessDefinition();
        processEngine.getProcessEngine().getRuntimeService().startProcessInstanceByKey(KEY);
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getBpmnFiles() {
        return new String[] {
                "com/test/activiti/autowiredservicetask/AutoWireServiceTask.bpmn"};
    }

}
```

*I hope you got your desired answer*

Comment: Thanks Mehdi Tahmasebi for your reference implementation!

Comment: @ManjunathMahashetti You're welcome, did it solve your question?